# Display text on icon hover using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover

What I'm after is three icons to be displayed at all times in a row. Then, once one of the icons is hovered over, text displays underneath all three. Then, once the next icon is hovered over, different text etc. When no icon is hovered over, no text displays. I saw something very similar done using HTML and CSS so was wondering where I've gone wrong.

Thanks in advance

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.fa {
  padding: 20px;
}

#twitterText,
#facebookText,
#instagramText {
  display: none;
}

.fa-twitter:hover + #twitterText {
  display: block;
}

.fa-facebook:hover + #facebookText {
  display: block;
}

.fa-instagram:hover + #instagramText {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-5x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-instagram fa-5x"></i>

<p id="twitterText">Twitter</p>
<p id="facebookText">Facebook</p>
<p id="instagramText">Instagram</p>
```

Comment: _"so was wondering where I've gone wrong"_ - in using `+`, see  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 5):

replae `+` with `~` which indicate successor sibling

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.fa {
  padding: 20px;
}

#twitterText,
#facebookText,
#instagramText {
  display: none;
}

.fa-twitter:hover ~ #twitterText {
  display: block;
}

.fa-facebook:hover ~ #facebookText {
  display: block;
}

.fa-instagram:hover ~ #instagramText {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-5x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-instagram fa-5x"></i>

<p id="twitterText">Twitter</p>
<p id="facebookText">Facebook</p>
<p id="instagramText">Instagram</p>
```